# How do I replace character codes in transact-sql?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to fix Microsoft word smart quotes (and other word smart characters) that were inserted into some content due to copy/paste.  While we are working on a permanent solution to this I am trying to create a script so we can fix the data as it becomes an issue.

To test it out I"m running the following query: `select title from DigArticleArticle where ArticleId = 8249`.  This correctly retrieves our title, complete with the question mark due to the invalid character.  To replace this I tried the following query:

```
select REPLACE(title, CHAR(8216), char(39)), Title from DigArticleArticle where ArticleID = 8249
```

This returns null as the first column.  Why would my replace return null?  Even if the character code isn't found it should still return the original string.

Comment: IS DigArticleArticle the same table as Article?

Comment: Yes, sorry I typed the first one and copied the second line.  I"ll fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN Docs on the argument [for char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx)

> CHAR ( integer_expression )
>
> Arguments
>
> integer_expression
>
> Is an integer from 0 through 255. NULL is returned  if the integer expression is not in this range.

8216 is larger than 255 so its null

[For replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

> Return Types
>
> Returns nvarchar if one of the input arguments is of the nvarchar data type; otherwise, REPLACE returns varchar.
>
> Returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL.

So you'll always get back null if `char(8216)` is an argument in replace

As per [trekstuff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146241/119477) you should use nchar instead

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select REPLACE(title, NCHAR(8216), char(39)), Title from DigArticleArticle where ArticleID = 8249
```

As mentioned above CHAR() deals with ASCII characters (0-255). In this case Unicode version is needed, NCHAR() can deal with range 0-65535

Comment: +1 but you might consider improving your answer to explain your code why it will help. e.g. *the argument for nchar has a range of 0-65,535 which supports Unicode while char() only supports only ascii...* for more see the meta question [Explaining entirely code-based answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/)

Comment: Thanks for advice, added explanation as well.